# Determine class of special function from algebraic constraints?

Tags: special-functions, expression-construction, constraint

Consider vectors `x_i` in arbitrary dimension. Let's say I have an expression in six variables `F[x_1,x_2,x_3][x_4,x_5,x_6]`, which actually can only really depend on scalars `a[i,j]=x_i.x_j`. It has two kinds of input parameters. Permutations of the second and third argument in both input fields leave the function invariant i.e.

```
F[x_1,x_2,x_3][x_4,x_5,x_6] == F[x_1,x_2,x_3][x_4,x_6,x_5]
F[x_1,x_2,x_3][x_4,x_5,x_6] == F[x_1,x_3,x_2][x_4,x_5,x_6]
F[x_1,x_2,x_3][x_4,x_5,x_6] == F[x_1,x_3,x_2][x_4,x_6,x_5]
```

while a permutation within the input fields that changes the first argument will transform the function non-trivially, so i.e.

```
F[x_1,x_2,x_3][x_4,x_5,x_6] != F[x_2,x_1,x_3][x_4,x_5,x_6]
F[x_1,x_2,x_3][x_4,x_5,x_6] != F[x_1,x_2,x_3][x_6,x_5,x_4]
(* etc. *)
```

For this reason, we can abbreviate the function as `F[x_1,x_2,x_3][x_4,x_5,x_6] -> C[1,4]`, displaying only the first argument of each set of inputs. Since the remaining two are permutation invariant this specifies the argument structure sufficiently.

Furthermore, it is known that this function satisfies algebraic constraints. For instance, two of the constraints are:

```
0 == a[1, 6] C[6, 1] + a[2, 6] C[6, 2] + a[3, 6] C[6, 3]
```

(and index permutations thereof), and

```
0 == -a[4, 5] + a[5, 6] + (a[1, 5] C[5, 1])/C[4, 1] + (a[2, 5] C[5, 2])/C[4, 2] + (a[3, 5] C[5, 3])/C[4, 3] - (a[1, 5] C[5, 1])/C[6, 1] - (a[2, 5] C[5, 2])/C[6, 2] - (a[3, 5] C[5, 3])/C[6, 3]
```

Using the permutation properties mentioned above and summing three different index permutations of the second constraint, namely:

```
cstr2 - (cstr2 /. {5 -> 6, 6 -> 5}) - (cstr2 /. {4 -> 5, 5 -> 4})
```

we can obtain a version of it that is permutation invariant in the second index of `C[i,j]`:

```
0 == a[1, 5] C[5, 1] (1/C[4, 1] - 1/C[6, 1]) + a[1, 4] C[4, 1] (-(1/C[5, 1]) + 1/C[6, 1]) + a[1, 6] (-(1/C[4, 1]) + 1/C[5, 1]) C[6, 1] + a[2, 5] C[5, 2] (1/C[4, 2] - 1/C[6, 2]) + a[2, 4] C[4, 2] (-(1/C[5, 2]) + 1/C[6, 2]) + a[2, 6] (-(1/C[4, 2]) + 1/C[5, 2]) C[6, 2] + a[3, 5] C[5, 3] (1/C[4, 3] - 1/C[6, 3]) + a[3, 4] C[4, 3] (-(1/C[5, 3]) + 1/C[6, 3]) + a[3, 6] (-(1/C[4, 3]) + 1/C[5, 3]) C[6, 3]
```

More such constraints can be derived, linearly independent of the ones mentioned above. But further constraints are expected to get more and more involved. Now, my question is whether Mathematica can determine the class of special functions as an Ansatz for `F[x_1,x_2,x_3][x_4,x_5,x_6]` from a given set of constraints, as given above? Especially the first constraint seems simple enough and I assume only a finite set of special functions would sum to zero under three index permutations. Any hint on how to go about figuring out these special functions would be very useful. Thanks for any suggestion.

Comment: This problem sounds hard (especially implementing it in MMA?), but off the top of my head, I would suggest generating a differential equation from your lists of constraints and seeing what special functions might satisfy that differential equation.

Comment: I don't understand your C[i,j] notation.

Comment: @march Thanks for the suggestion! Is there a standard procedure on how to convert algebraic constraints to differential equations?

Comment: @DanielLichtblau The `i` in `C[i,j]` denotes the index of the variable `x_1` in `F[x_1,x_2,x_3][x_4,x_5,x_6]`, while the `j` denotes the index of variable `x_4`. Due to the index permutation properties that this function satisfies it is sufficient to give only these two indices to be able to map one-to-one between `C[i,j]` and `F[x_1,x_2,x_3][x_4,x_5,x_6]`.

Comment: I mean, this isn't a standard procedure as far as I know; I've just used it in the past (with middling success). Take the derivative of your last equation, say, with respect to the argument of the function (not with respect to the parameters!). The point is to try to reduce the equation to some differential equation for your function, and then look up the result in a table of differential equations.

Comment: Ok, that's a strategy. Thanks! i will give it a try.